# How to evaluate all possible contrasts of an interaction effect

Tags: r, regression, interaction

Let's say I have an experiment where I pair people up with either individuals of the same political orientation, or different.  I track before and after measures of a respondent's belief in global warming.

Consider the following specification:

```
fit <- lm_robust(
  belief_global_warming  ~ politics + partner_politics + partner_politics + politics * partner_politics + sex,
  data = data,
  clusters = team_id,
  se = "stata"
)
```

Let's say the output for the coefficients of interest look like so:

```
                                               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) CI Lower CI Upper  DF
politicsRepublican                              6.3265     2.6573  2.3808  0.01893   1.0625  11.5905 114
partner_politicsRepublican                      1.2334     1.5024  0.8210  0.41338  -1.7428   4.2096 114
politicsRepublican:partner_politicsRepublican  -6.5873     2.9706 -2.2175  0.02857 -12.4720  -0.7026 114
```

So, the reference group auto-selected by R is Democrats paired with Democrats.  I want to be able to say that a D paired with an R has different response in the DV than any of the other combinations (RD, RR, DD).

What is the appropriate way to do the following:

(1) Compare mixed groups (Republican paired with Democrat or Democrat paired with Republican) against all other groupings to detect if before and after changes are significant relative to all reference groups, while also controlling for multiple tests.

My thought was to just set a different reference group and run all the possible combinations, but I remembered Stata's contrast command, and wonder if there's a parsimonious R equivalent.

(2) Is putting the DV as a before-and-after change the appropriate method? I have heard a suggestion about keeping the DV a level and have before and after dummies (like a D-I-D approach), but I'm not sure I understand it.

Comment: What type of scale do you use to measure a respondent's believe? You might want to transform it somehow or model it by some alternative distribution than normal because changes might not be the same everywhere on the scale (e.g. if you have a number of binary items then response could be modeled as a binomial or beta-binomial distributed variable).

Comment: 0 to 100 scale on the strength of belief

Comment: how did you obtain that scale. What kind of questions is it based on?

Comment: To what extent do you believe that climate change is anthropogenic? 100 representing “completely agree”, 0 representing “completely disagree”

Comment: could you provide some descriptive statistics or a graphics like a histogram plots or a scatter plot with before versus after.

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m on my phone, but I’m not sure how that would make the problem any more tractable. It’s a continuous variable that goes from 0-100. The nature of the DV isn’t what’s challenging — it’s getting an omnibus test statistic that tests all possible contrasts

Comment: It is just to make an answer/example that is brewing in my mind more specific to your case. It is not gonna change the answer to your question (1) and (2) but your problem may have some quirks that may be helped with at the same time (e.g. for a scale from 0 to 100 you can not really have a normal distribution of error terms). Actually, I have an answer for both 1 and 2 in my head but I am looking for a nice way to present it (so this means I need to come up with my own data).

Comment: I’m excited to hear it! When I get home I can post a few descriptives. I’m sure your answer will be in enormously helpful because most of my questions are on a 0 to 100 scale. If it helps your thinking process at all… I’m also hoping to transform these variables in a secondary analysis into some kind of aggregate index that tracks overall belief change (agnostic of the actual subject of those beliefs)...like a latent variable for belief change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84270/discussion-between-martijn-weterings-and-parseltongue).

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the `lm_robust` function before, but I would suggest a logistic regression model for this study, which you can do with the `glm()` function. It would allow you to compare mixed groups to both types of non-mixed groups (question 1) and allow you to analyze the predictors of changing beliefs (question 2).

Set up your data in an $n by 5$ data frame with variables $Pair=\left\{1,...,n\right\}$, $Type 1=\left\{0,1\right\}$, $Type 2=\left\{0,1\right\}$, and $Change=\left\{0,1\right\}$, where $Pair$ is an identifying variable, $Type 1$ describes if they were in a Republican/Republican group, $Type 2$ describes if they were in a Democrat/Democrat groups, and $Change$ describes whether their beliefs changed. For example:

```
Pair     Type 1     Type 2     Change
1        0          0          1
2        0          1          0
3        1          0          1 
4        1          0          0
.        .          .          .
.        .          .          .
.        .          .          .
```

This would make mixed groups your reference group, such that for mixed groups $Type1=0$ and $Type2=0$.

Now, use R to do a logistic regression and analyze it:

```
mod=glm(Change~Type1+Type2,family='binomial')
summary(mod)
confint(mod)
exp(coef(mod))/(1+exp(coef(mod)))
```

This creates model, summarizes it, gives confidence intervals, and gives odds ratios. The odds ratios are one way to answer both your questions. Probabilities are also another way to answer both your questions.The probability of changing beliefs is given by

$$\pi(change=1)=\frac{exp(\beta_0+\beta_1*Type1+\beta_2*Type2)}{1+exp(\beta_0+\beta_1*Type1+\beta_2*Type2)}$$

Thus, for mixed groups, the probability of change is

$$\pi(change=1|Type=Mixed)=\frac{exp(\beta_0+\beta_1*0+\beta_2*0)}{1+exp(\beta_0+\beta_1*0+\beta_2*0)}=\frac{exp(\beta_0)}{1+exp(\beta_0)}$$

and the probability of change for a Republican/Republican group is

$$\pi(change=1|Type=RR)=\frac{exp(\beta_0+\beta_1*1+\beta_2*0)}{1+exp(\beta_0+\beta_1*1+\beta_2*0)}=\frac{exp(\beta_0+\beta_1)}{1+exp(\beta_0+\beta_1)}$$

and the probability of change for a Democrat/Democrat group is

$$\pi(change=1|Type=DD)=\frac{exp(\beta_0+\beta_1*0+\beta_2*1)}{1+exp(\beta_0+\beta_1*0+\beta_2*1)}=\frac{exp(\beta_0+\beta_2)}{1+exp(\beta_0+\beta_2)}$$

Comment: (1) You changed the structure of the interactions. In your model there is not difference in the odds of change for a democrat when it is paired with a republican and a republican when it is paired with a democrat. I believe that this is not a good suggestion/solution. The current model shows that republicans paired with a democratic partner have more change in their belief  (+6.3265) then democrats paired with a republican partner (+1.2334). (2) The change to a logistic regression model is not very clear. The OP is talking about a *continuous* dependent variable.

Comment: If you know of a robust literature on the validity of such a continuous variable, please share, but the OP does not share this information. If there is indeed a difference between D with R vs R with D they can make another `Type` variable.

Comment: To me this seems like a standard repeated measures case, where there is some measurement of belief before and after. This should not (neccesarily) be modeled as a logistic regression, or at least not a logistic regression with a variable dummy  'change' since the data contains much more nuance then just this binary dependent variable (but possibly the data might be binomial distributed in which case a logistic regression could help).

Comment: Fair enough. A dyadic longitudinal hierarchical linear model might be appropriate. I'm open to editing my answer if the OP so requests.

Comment: I had the same concern as Martijn, and would appreciate an edit to that effect. The DV is continuous. Furthermore, you collapse the mixed groups into a homogenous category. In fact, the effect of a dem paired with a repub is different than a repub paired with a dem.